# Postman format console log output

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm using the open source version of Postman

I have a console log output in the Pre-Request script for each of my API calls, which just outputs the title of the call.

Is there a way of formatting the console log output in postman to make it stand out in the console log? I want to either enlarge or bold the text or make it a different colour so it is clear in the console log.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible, though console output gets some different colors for error codes or strings. 
javascript string formatting doesn't work either. You should output some visible strings like you would do in normal consoles like:

```
console.log("******************************");
console.log("*********   MY TEST   ********");
console.log("******************************");
```

sorry, can't see a better way

Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

In node.js there is by using escape sequence:

```
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[34m%s\x1b[0m', 'I am cyan','i am blue');
```

So you should be able to if running Newman as a library within Node. And there is a way to provide colors for browser based console.log; however, not in the desktop application. I too would much appreciate some simple formatting to help my log events to stand out from the rest. But I have resorted to using something similar to a-joly's response above

```
console.log("******************************");
console.log("*********   MY TEST   ********");
console.log("******************************");
```

to help with this issue.

There are other formatting styles capable within Node's console.log as well, they can be viewed [here](http://voidcanvas.com/make-console-log-output-colorful-and-stylish-in-browser-node/):